# Issue in adding $my_elements inside the array

Tags: php, codeigniter

My aim is to reduce the elements which matches the numbers from one array to another.

```
$my_elements = "329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340";

$my_array =array(329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,359);

$to_remove = array($my_elements);

$result = array_diff($my_array,$to_remove);

$str_comp=implode(",", $result);

echo $str_comp;
```

I want to show this result:

341,342,359

Please help with this.

```
$my_elements = "329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340";

$my_array =array(329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,359);

$to_remove = array($my_elements);

$result = array_diff($my_array,$to_remove);

$str_comp=implode(",", $result);

echo $str_comp;
```

Comment: `$my_elements` is a string, not an array. When you convert it to an array, it is an array with 1 element; that string. You need to use `explode()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$to_remove`  should be array of numbers from `$my_elements` string. However, using `array($my_elements)` does not do this. You need to `explode` your string to get array of numbers:

```
$my_elements = "329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340";

$my_array =array(329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,359);

// Change is here
$to_remove = explode(',', $my_elements);

$result = array_diff($my_array,$to_remove);

$str_comp=implode(",", $result);

echo $str_comp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the array, if value does not exist in the second array, push it in a new array

```
$data = explode(",",$my_elements)
$finalData = array();

foreach($data as $value){
  if(!in_array($value,$my_array)){
     $finalData[] = $value;
   }
}
```

`$finalData` will have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

my_elements should be an array

```
$my_elements = explode(',',"329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340");
```

Replace your code with the following:-

```
$my_elements = explode(',',"329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340");

$my_array =array(329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,359);


$result = array_diff($my_array,$my_elements);

$str_comp=implode(",", $result);

echo $str_comp;
```

Output:-

```
341,342,359
```